# In Pygame, when building a character, why are we using x,y when we are already giving the width and height?

Tags: python

[the pygame code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eoxgr.png)

I am not understanding why we are putting x,y when we already have width and height for the character. Just wanted to know what's the use of x,y in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From these informations, it could mean many things, but the most likely is that, the `width` and `height` are the character's width and height, while the `x` and `y` are the position of the character in the world.